# css if there is a specific subclass, change the main class property

Tags: html, css, layout, sass, flexbox

There is a class called main-layout. If there is a class named side-nav in the layout, i want to give padding left to the main-layout.

I tried these ways but it didn't work

```
.main-layout:has(.side-nav) {
   padding-left: 185px;
}

.main-layout .side-nav .main-layout {
   padding-left: 185px;
}

.main-layout .side-nav + .main-layout {
   padding-left: 185px;
}

.main-layout .side-nav ~ .main-layout {
   padding-left: 185px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood from your question is you want to give padding to the main layout. Please find below code if it helps you!
[image]

```css
.main-layout {
    padding-left: 185px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-layout">
      <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
      <div class="side-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```